# Sqlite : count how many times a value is inserted

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database in which product names are getting introduced.What i want to do,is have another column in which it counts how many times a name is getting introduced.I don't want to have duplicates(that's why UNIQUE is set) so for example when "cake" is introduced first,the counter is set to 1.Everytime cake is introdued,the counter will increase by 1.

I searched in here and on google but i can't find anything, and if i find something,because i have no database experience,i don't know how to implement it.Could you please help me with a snippet and some short explanations,i want to learn but i can't find too many resources on this matter.
Thanks in advance,have a nice day !

Here's my database activity :

```
public class SQLiteCountryAssistant extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static final String DB_NAME = "usingsqlite.db";
private static final int DB_VERSION_NUMBER = 1;
private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "countries";
private static final String DB_COLUMN_1_NAME = "country_name";
private static final String DB_COLUMN_2_NAME = "country_counter";

private static final String DB_CREATE_SCRIPT = "create table " + DB_TABLE_NAME +
                        " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, country_name text UNIQUE,country_counter int);)";

private SQLiteDatabase sqliteDBInstance = null;

public SQLiteCountryAssistant(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION_NUMBER);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    // TODO: Implement onUpgrade
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqliteDBInstance)
{
    Log.i("onCreate", "Creating the database...");
    sqliteDBInstance.execSQL(DB_CREATE_SCRIPT);
}

public void openDB() throws SQLException
{
    Log.i("openDB", "Checking sqliteDBInstance...");
    if(this.sqliteDBInstance == null)
    {
        Log.i("openDB", "Creating sqliteDBInstance...");
        this.sqliteDBInstance = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }
}

public void closeDB()
{
    if(this.sqliteDBInstance != null)
    {
        if(this.sqliteDBInstance.isOpen())
            this.sqliteDBInstance.close();
    }
}

public long insertCountry(String countryName)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME, countryName);

    return this.sqliteDBInstance.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
}

public boolean removeCountry(String countryName)
{
    int result = this.sqliteDBInstance.delete(DB_TABLE_NAME, "country_name='" + countryName + "'", null);

    if(result > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public long updateCountry(String oldCountryName, String newCountryName)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME, newCountryName);
    return this.sqliteDBInstance.update(DB_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "country_name='" + oldCountryName + "'", null);
}

public String[] getAllCountries()
{
    Cursor cursor = this.sqliteDBInstance.query(DB_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {DB_COLUMN_1_NAME}, null, null, null, null, DB_COLUMN_1_NAME + " ASC");

    if(cursor.getCount() >0)
    {
        String[] str = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;

        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
             str[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME));
             i++;
         }
        return str;
    }
    else
    {
        return new String[] {};
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is change your insert function.  Instead of just inserting the data, it needs to first check if that country already exists.  If so, you need to get the current value, increment it, and update that row.  If not, you insert it with a count of 1.

Your remove function will need to match that-  check if it exists and get the count.  If the count is 1, remove it.  Otherwise get the old count, decrement it, and update the row.  Or alternatively you can allow it to have a count of 0 and not do the remove, but then you need to remove that row from get queries, which I really don't suggest.

If perfomance isn't an issue you can just do this all in code in 2 or 3 queries each.  If it is an issue, you can use some fancy raw SQL queries to reduce the number of db round trips.

Comment: Well,performance isn't an issue,i'll have like 200 entries ? maybe a bit more,but i guess that's not an issue.What you described above sounds great but..how can i achieve that ? What do i need to use ?

Comment: I tried a couple of stuff with execsql but i didn't even get close to making it work..